# Best way to handle tap gestures

Tags: javascript, html5, event-handling, mobile

I'm building a small web app primarily for mobile use. I have some widgets that need to handle tap gestures in the expected way, and I don't feel this one feature is reason enough to include JQuery mobile.

I've written the following function for making an element respond to "tap" events:

```
function bind_tap(el, cb) {
  (function(){
    var touchStarted = false;
    el.addEventListener("click", cb, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){
      touchStarted = true;
    }, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchcancel", function(){
      touchStarted = false;
    }, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchleave", function(){
      touchStarted = false;
    }, false);
    el.addEventListener("touchend", function(){
      touchStarted = false;
      if (touchStarted) cb();
    }, false);
  })();
};
```

It seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if it could/should be improved in any way, either in that parts of it are redundant (I'm not sure what `touchcancel` really means) or to handle some edge case I haven't thought of.

---

#### Solution so far:

```
function bindTap(element, callback, useCapture) {
  var touchStarted = false, touchFinished = null;
  useCapture = !!useCapture;
  function startTap() {
      touchStarted = true;
      touchFinished = false;
  }
  function cancelTap() {
      touchStarted = false;
  }
  function completeTap() {
      if (touchStarted && !touchFinished) {
          callback.apply(this, arguments);
          touchFinished = true;
      }
  }
  function handleClick() {
      touchStarted = true;
      completeTap.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  element.addEventListener("click", handleClick, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("touchstart", startTap, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("touchcancel", cancelTap, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("touchleave", cancelTap, useCapture);
  element.addEventListener("touchend", completeTap, useCapture);
}
```

Comment: have you tried this http://benhowdle.im/touche/

Comment: That looks cool, though my goal here is to minimise external dependencies. Interesting to note *Touche* only listens for the `touchend` event.

Answer (score 3):

For your purposes, you can treat `touchleave` and `touchcancel` the same way. The difference is `touchleave` happens when the touch point leaves the element and moves somewhere else in the document, and `touchcancel` happens when the touch point leaves the document entirely, like moving outside the browser window's content area or onto a plugin.

Minor stuff:

- The functions you use to handle `touchleave` and `touchcancel` are exactly the same, so you could eliminate redundancy by reusing the same function for both.
- The third argument to `addEventListner`, `useCapture`, defaults to `false`, so you don't need to explicitly pass it in.
- The IIFE inside of `bind_tap` serves no purpose, it can be removed.
- JavaScript identifiers should use *camelCase*; `bind_tap` is not an appropriate name for an identifier.
- Variables named like `el` and `cb` aren't a big deal for internal stuff, but for code that's exposed as part of your API (function parameters) they should probably have fully descriptive names.
- You have an extra semicolon at the end of your code. Function declarations are not separated by (or terminated with) semicolons.

Major stuff:

- In your `touchend` handler you set `touchStarted` to false and then check it for a truthy value on the next line; `if (touchStarted) cb();`. The callback will never fire there. The code is only working because you have the callback handling the `click` event. When you fix this, you'll need to make sure that the callback only fires once. I added `touchFinished` in the example below to address that.
- You probably want to pass the `this` binding and any arguments on to the callback.

---

Something like this should work (not tested).

```
function bindTap(element, callback) {
    var touchStarted = false,
        touchFinished = false;

    function startTap() {
        touchStarted = true;
    }

    function cancelTap() {
        touchStarted = false;
    }

    function endTap() {
        if (touchStarted && !touchFinished) {
            callback.apply(this, arguments);
            touchFinished = true;
        }
    }

    function handleClick() {
        touchStarted = true;
        endTap.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    element.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    element.addEventListener("touchstart", startTap);
    element.addEventListener("touchcancel", cancelTap);
    element.addEventListener("touchleave", cancelTap);
    element.addEventListener("touchend", endTap);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I don't know how i missed the first major point! But in your solution; I don't think the touchFinished mechanism works. It effectively kills the listener after its fired once, whereas in my testing so far (IOS safari web inspector and chrome dev tools emulator) tap and click never seem to both be triggered.

Comment: @Nat, ah, you're right. Adding `touchFinished = false;` to `startTap` should fix that, no?

Comment: Isn't it necessary then to also include `touchFinished = false;` in the handleClick function? Just wondering, why the concern for the event being triggered twice? i.e. what problem exactly does `touchFinished` solve?

Comment: @Nat Probably, yeah, assuming the click event always fires after the touchend event. You're calling the callback from both `click` and `touchend` events, so if both events fire (which they probably will), the callback will run twice. So the idea is to set a flag when the callback is called, and not call it again for the same action.